# How big are the Choedan Kal?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

The Choedan Kal are two large statues that are the focus of the One Power in the *Wheel of Time* series, both of which were mostly buried.  Is there any specifications on their heights?  Every wiki I've found says "massive" but did they ever give anything more specific, or relate it's height to anything in the surrounding area?  Like "It was as tall as the nearby trees" or "a finger was each a man tall"?

Comment: Fixed, was going to say destroyed but not sure if that’s correct

Comment: Guess I was editing at the same moment :-)

Comment: Gah two good answers that give detailed and concise information, I don't know which one to pick :(

Comment: Since we've got two quite different results, I think both answers should elaborate a bit on the assumptions used to get there. (Working on that for my answer now.) Then you can decide which set of assumptions you think is more realistic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a total height in the book, but we do have a measurement to work with.

> Out of the clay at the bottom of the pit slanted a gigantic stone hand
> holding a crystal sphere, and it was this that shone with the last
> sunlight. Rand gaped at the size of it, a smooth ball—he was sure not
> so much as a scratch marred its surface—at least twenty paces through.
>
> Some distance away from the hand, a stone face in proportion had been
> uncovered. A bearded man's face, it thrust out of the soil with the
> dignity of vast years; the broad features seemed to hold wisdom and
> knowledge. -The Great Hunt
>
> Length, units of: 10 inches = 3 hands = 1 foot; 3 feet = 1 pace; 2
> paces = 1 span; 1000 spans = 1 mile; 4 miles = 1 league. - Appendix

The average US male has a hand length of about 7.5 inches(19cm), and a height of 70 inches(178cm).

With some guess work on how long the hand is vs the sphere itself, math blah blah blah.

If the length of the hand is 60 Wheel of Time feet (20 paces at 1 pace = 3 Wheel of Time feet) using our average proportioned US male ratio,

the **Choedan Kal stood at about 560 Wheel of Time Feet** or **converted from Wheel of Time measurements 467 US Feet(142 meter)**.

As a basis for my assumption that the hand is about the same diameter as the orb here is the official cover for Winters Heart. As Muru states in a comment, The access Ter'angreal (which is what it appears we see in the book cover) are identical but miniature of the large Sa'angreal.

[image]

Comment: It would really help if you could provide SI approximations for your measurements...

Comment: @DavidW will do, robert jordan used US measurements in his appendix so ill have to add in the conversions for you other folk :P

Comment: @Himarm +1 for the units he used, but if you gave me SI that'd be awesome too.

Comment: "1 pace = 3 feet" - the standard figure I found was 30 inches or 2.5 feet.

Comment: @Himarm Thank you.  Some of us speak the language, but not exactly the same. :)  (Wasn't there a quote along the lines of "divided by a common language?" :)

Comment: "some guess work on how long the hand is vs the sphere itself, math blah blah blah" - could you elaborate a bit more on this? I'm curious why we're getting two quite different answers.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Based on the ultimate ratio, I'd say his sphere is almost twice as large - relative to the hand - as yours.  Also, I think your average person might be a bit taller; 250/150 = 1.67m (min) to 250/120 = 2.08m (max) vs. 70 in ~ 1.78m.

Answer (score 6):

The best place to check is Book 2, Chapter 20, when Rand first sees the male Choedan Kal statue. At this point neither Rand nor we the readers know what it is, or even the words Choedan Kal - it's just a big statue to us, and for that reason it's described in more detail than later.

> His eyes on the reflection, he was surprised when Red suddenly stopped. On the point of urging the bay on, he realized that they stood on the edge of a clay precipice, above a huge excavation. Most of the hill had been dug away to a depth of easily a hundred paces. Certainly more than one hill had vanished, and maybe some farmers' fields, for the hole was at least ten times as wide as it was deep. The far side appeared to have been packed hard to a ramp. There were men on the bottom, a dozen of them, getting a fire started; down there, night was already descending. Here and there among them armor turned the light, and swords swung at their sides. He hardly glanced at them.
>
> Out of the clay at the bottom of the pit slanted a gigantic stone hand holding a crystal sphere, and it was this that shone with the last sunlight. Rand gaped at the size of it, a smooth ball — he was sure not so much as a scratch marred its surface — at least twenty paces through.
>
> Some distance away from the hand, a stone face in proportion had been uncovered. A bearded man's face, it thrust out of the soil with the dignity of vast years; the broad features seemed to hold wisdom and knowledge.

The statue's hand is holding a ball which is **twenty paces (around 600 inches or 50 feet) in diameter**. Now we don't know exactly how big the ball is compared to the hand, but I'm assuming the hand is firmly clasping the ball, something like this (*non-canonical*) picture:

[image]

At a rough estimation, I guess I could comfortably hold a ball perhaps 4-5 inches in diameter like this. That would make the statue around **120-150 times life size**, assuming it's proportional. So the statue is, at a *very* rough estimate:

### around **250 metres high**.

Comment: Perhaps another approach: the excavation is 100+ paces (250+ ft, 75+ m) deep and all they've uncovered so far is its head and a hand. Assuming that the head/hand weren't buried too deeply underground, that easily puts the statue on the same scale as [the largest statues in our world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_statues), if not larger. TL;DR it's **huge**, even by our standards.

Comment: Aren't the keys miniature versions of the statues? If so, they ball would be much bigger going by the cover of *Winter's Heart*: https://i0.wp.com/www.tor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/winters-heart-ebook.jpg

Comment: @muru The cover art has never been considered canonical. [Jordan complained about its inaccuracy as far back as 1993.](https://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=15#3)

Comment: @duskwuff maru linked an ebook cover art, and afaik, most of the ebooks got new cover art about when jordan died so he may have never seen this to criticize or approve.